# How to set badge notification for Qt on Mac

Tags: macos, qt, badge, dock, nsdocktile

I want to set badge (notification number) on mac application using Qt,

I also try QApplication::setWindowIcon() but it's only change the icon on window and dialog, not the icon on dock.
Is there anyway to set badge using Qt ? Can I call cocoa methods from Qt to set badge ?

Thank you

Answer (score 7):

If you're using Qt 5.3, you're in luck!  Badge notification numbers are supported in the [Qt Mac Extras](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtmacextras-index.html) package.  Specifically, see [QtMac::setApplicationIconBadgeNumber()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtmac.html#setApplicationIconBadgeNumber)

Comment: Thanks, you save me alot :D
(can't believe I did not found it +_+!)

Answer (score 0):

The dock icon is provided by whatever `.icns` file your app uses, which is reflected by the icon in Finder, you can set it with `ICON = /path/to/your/icon.icns` in your `.pro` file. For setting notifications for your app you have to jump into the Objective-C++ bridge, but there's an answer here that shows how to do it: [Mac OS UserNotificationCenter in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22142592/mac-os-usernotificationcenter-in-qt).